# Show content after div background loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I display all the contents of my site just after the background of the div to be loaded?
As the fund is only a preview layout, it is very heavy, so I want it to be shown only after loading.

I tried using $ (document).ready() but it did not work. 
Below is my attempt that went wrong:

HTML Code:

```
<!-- This is a DIV with Background -->
<div class="example" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".example").show();
})
```

Thus the div is displayed after loading the page and not after your background loaded. 
How can I do?

Comment: Is the background set in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

instead of document ready use window load - but it will wait for all other images and resources to load to get executed

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $(".example").show();
})
```